# How to get option value from option label of a specific attribute

Tags: magento2, attributes

I'm looking for having attribute option value from its label
 Indeed I have a list of labels ans I want to generate their value s of each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First load your product attribute from its attribute code

   /**
   \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
   */

   /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute $eavAttribute */
   $productAttribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, $attributeCode);
2. Then, load all its options:

   ```
   if (is_object($productAttribute) && $productAttribute->usesSource()) {
                   $allOptions = $productAttribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
   ```

   }
3. Finally, find the option value from the label:

   /**
   Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table $eavSourceTable
   */

   $attributeTable     = $eavSourceTable->setAttribute($attribute);
   $allOptions         = $eavSourceTable->getAllOptions(false);

   ```
       foreach ($allOptions as $option) {
           if ($option['label'] == $label) {
               return $option['value'];
           }
       }

       $count = count($allOptions) +1;

       $data['option']['value']['option_' . $count] = [$label,''];
       $attribute->addData($data);
       $attribute->getResource()->save($attribute);

       $attributeTable        = $eavSourceTable->setAttribute($attribute);
       $options               = $eavSourceTable->getAllOptions(false);

       foreach ($options as $option) {
           if ($option['label'] == $label) {
               return $option['value'];
           }
       }
   ```

all this code, will need to be part of a class. I imagine you see from there where to put this code and where to declare the dependencies for it

Comment: Thank you for your answer !but it's not clear for me

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Nouari, if you could point me to an answer that you have accepted, I may see how I can change my answer to suit you

Comment: Ok, it's done then, I have already a code if you can verify this for me please, can we continue on a discussion?

Comment: I'm there too !

Comment: Hi, I used your module can you show me how to call it in a phtml file please

Comment: are u available plz?